# Electron React Native for Web Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, electron, keyboard-shortcuts, react-native-web

I am trying to add keyboard shortcuts specifically for the electron (web) build of a react-native-web app.

I do have some shortcuts already defined as accelerators in `index.electron.js` but I want these new shortcuts to not live in the menu and they require react actions/reducers to execute.

I tried adding `window.onkeydown = (e) => {` into a `App.web.js::componentDidMount` however this only works when running the app in a browser. When I build the application and run it in electron (which runs the `.web` versions of files) I get a crash regarding `window` not being defined.

I'm stumped on how to go about adding keyboard shortcuts/event listeners (that trigger react-specific code) to an Electron app that is built using React-Native for web.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Electron API [`globalShortcut`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut) and [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args) to send events to web page.

Main process code

```js
  const { globalShortcut } = require('electron')

  // this will be triggered when the accelerator is pressed
  // even if the app is in the background
  const ret = globalShortcut.register("Your_Accelerator", () => {
    yourWindow.webContents.send("shortcut", "shortcut has been pressed")
  });

  if (!ret) {
    console.log("registration failed");
  } else {
    console.log("registration succeeded");
  }
```

Renderer process code

```js
  const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
  ipcRenderer.on("shortcut", (event, message) => {
    console.log(message) // Prints "shortcut has been pressed"
  })
```

Comment: To clarify, where is the main process code? In `index.electron.js`? Would I ten import the `ipcRenderer` into my react component?

Comment: I have no idea what your project structure looks like and I'm not familiar with "React native for web". However, I have a couple of notes, you say "window" is undefined, I think you're trying to run renderer code inside the main process which is causing this issue. Please look into Electron applications structure and get to know the difference between what we call the "Main" process and "Renderer" processes. This would be a good place to start: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes

Comment: BTW, `window.onkeydown` should work in Electron like it would work in Chrome (if you run it inside the Renderer process correctly). I just think `globalShortcut` is better because it allows you to enable shortcuts even if your app doesn't have focus. But of course, that depends on your use case.

Comment: I'm simply trying to run window from inside a random component's componentDidMount. Thanks for the link I will give it a read tomorrow morning :)

Comment: You should be able to do that easily with a bit of work. Remember, Electron just runs your web app inside Chromium, so it should behave the same way as it does in the browser (if you have the right project setup). Good luck!

Comment: Hey @aabuhijleh what object am I supposed to register my accelerator on if I don't want it to trigger when app is out of focus?

Comment: Seems to me that `window.onkeydown` fits your needs better. If you want to continue using `globalShortcut` APIs, you can listen to your `browserWindow`'s [`blur`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-blur) and `focus` events and unregister the shortcut on blur then register it again when you get back focus.

Answer (score 1):

I don't often use react-native, so I'm not sure if it's possible to do this with just the framework.
Assuming you're using `npm` you could just download a package that can support this. [react-hotkeys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hotkeys) sounds like it can do what you need shortcuts for.